# Comparing HttpStatus.SC_OK and INT variable

Tags: android, apache-httpcomponents

I made a method to check whether an http server is responding ok.
I'm using apache components.

```
private static int CheckAvailabilityHttp(String pHostName, int pPort)
{
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(String.format("http://%s:%s",pHostName,pPort));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == status) { // HttpStatus.SC_OK is 200 and status is 200
            return ServerStatuses.SUCCESS;
        }   
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ServerStatuses.FAILED;
}
```

The problem is on the comparison line:

```
if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == status)
```

Even though BOTH (HttpStatus.SC_OK and status variable) are 200, it doesn´t get inside the condition... It doesn't even throw an exception.

What I am doing wrong??

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure both are 200? Have you debugged in and viewed both values?

Answer (score 1):

Get the status code of the HTTP Response.

```
final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
    return null;
}
```

Tell me if this helps :)